# Using JSoup Selector for a class with a period in the name

Tags: jsoup

I'm using JSoup to select all the elements with class name article.text. The code looks like so:

```
Document pageDoc = Jsoup.connect(pageUrl).get();
Elements body = pageDoc.select(".article.text");
```

The body variable is always empty. It looks like the select strips out the .text and only looks for elements with a class type of "article". Is there any way to escape the period in article.text?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching for ".article\.text", or ".article.text"? Escape characters might be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried this and its working

```
Document pageDoc = Jsoup.connect(pageUrl).get();
Elements body = pageDoc.select("[class=article.text]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this :

`Elements body = pageDoc.getElementsByClass("article.text");`